# Get progress of firebase admin file upload

Tags: node.js, react-native, google-cloud-storage, firebase-storage, firebase-admin

I'm trying to get the progress of a 1 minute video uploading to firebase bucket storage using the admin sdk. I've seen a lot about using firebase.storage().ref.child..... but I'm unable to do that with the admin sdk since they don't have the same functions. This is my file upload:

```
exports.uploadMedia = (req, res) => {
    const BusBoy = require('busboy');
    const path = require('path');
    const os = require('os');
    const fs = require('fs');

    const busboy = new BusBoy({ headers: req.headers, limits: { files: 1, fileSize: 200000000 } });

    let mediaFileName;
    let mediaToBeUploaded = {};

    busboy.on('file', (fieldname, file, filename, encoding, mimetype) => {

        if(mimetype !== 'image/jpeg' && mimetype !== 'image/png' && mimetype !== 'video/quicktime' && mimetype !== 'video/mp4') {
            console.log(mimetype);
            return res.status(400).json({ error: 'Wrong file type submitted, only .png, .jpeg, .mov, and .mp4 files allowed'})
        }

        // my.image.png
        const imageExtension = filename.split('.')[filename.split('.').length - 1];
        
        //43523451452345231234.png
        mediaFileName = `${Math.round(Math.random()*100000000000)}.${imageExtension}`;
        const filepath = path.join(os.tmpdir(), mediaFileName);
        mediaToBeUploaded = { filepath, mimetype };
        file.pipe(fs.createWriteStream(filepath));

        file.on('limit', function(){
            fs.unlink(filepath, function(){
                return res.json({'Error': 'Max file size is 200 Mb, file size too large'});
            });
        });
    });
    busboy.on('finish', () => {
        admin
        .storage()
        .bucket()
        .upload(mediaToBeUploaded.filepath, {
            resumable: false,
            metadata: {
                metadata: {
                    contentType: mediaToBeUploaded.mimetype
                }
            }
        })
        .then(() => {
            const meadiaUrl = `https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/${config.storageBucket}/o/${mediaFileName}?alt=media`;
            return res.json({mediaUrl: meadiaUrl});
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            console.error(err);
            return res.json({'Error': 'Error uploading media'});
        });
    });
    req.pipe(busboy);
}
```

This works okay right now, but the only problem is that the user can't see where their 1 or 2 minute video upload is at. Currently, it's just a activity indicator and the user just sits their waiting without any notice. I'm using react native on the frontend if that helps with anything. Would appreciate any help!

Comment: Want to fully understand your question, you are uploading files from the backend in nodeJS to cloud Storage, and want to show in the frontend in react the upload progress right?

Comment: @SoniSol Exactly

Comment: Can you show us your react native piece of code responsible for the upload. The logic to show the progress has to be implemented on the client side.

Comment: That's the problem, I would rather not have any client side code for this upload, but it's turning out that I might need to.

Comment: You definitely have to have a client side code for this upload. You want to display it on the client side, only the client knows how and what to display.

Comment: as Lukasz said this will require clientside code to report the progress, please share your client side code so we can help you

Comment: Ah I see. I literally don't have any firebase client side code except for login. My page for uploading the posts is like 700 lines so there's no point in sharing all of that. I'm currently just sending the file to backend and the backend does the rest for now. I'm going to add the file upload to the client side and then return that URL link to send to the backend again. Thank you guys, I'll leave this open so I can post my solution later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to implement on the client side a lot easier... but it works perfect with image and video upload progress. On the backend, I was using the admin sdk, but frontend I was originally using the firebase sdk.

```
        this.uploadingMedia = true;
        const imageExtension = this.mediaFile.split('.')[this.mediaFile.split('.').length - 1];
        const mediaFileName = `${Math.round(Math.random()*100000000000)}.${imageExtension}`;
        const response = await fetch(this.mediaFile);
        const blob = await response.blob();
        const storageRef = storage.ref(`${mediaFileName}`).put(blob);
        storageRef.on(`state_changed`,snapshot=>{
          this.uploadProgress = (snapshot.bytesTransferred/snapshot.totalBytes);
        }, error=>{
          this.error = error.message;
          this.submitting = false;
          this.uploadingMedia = false;
          return;
        },
        async () => {
          storageRef.snapshot.ref.getDownloadURL().then(async (url)=>{
            imageUrl = [];
            videoUrl = [url];
            this.uploadingMedia = false;
            this.submitPost(imageUrl, videoUrl);
          });
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
export const uploadFile = (
  folderPath,
  fileName,
  file,
  generateDownloadURL = true,
  updateInformationUploadProgress
) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    try {
      const storageRef = firebaseApp.storage().ref(`${folderPath}/${fileName}`)
      const uploadTask = storageRef.put(file)

      uploadTask.on(
        'state_changed',
        snapshot => {
          if (updateInformationUploadProgress) {
            const progress =
              (snapshot.bytesTransferred / snapshot.totalBytes) * 100
            updateInformationUploadProgress({
              name: fileName,
              progress: progress,
            })
          }
        },
        error => {
          console.log('upload error: ', error)
          reject(error)
        },
        () => {
          if (generateDownloadURL) {
            uploadTask.snapshot.ref
              .getDownloadURL()
              .then(url => {
                resolve(url)
              })
              .catch(error => {
                console.log('url error: ', error.message)
                reject(error)
              })
          } else {
            resolve(uploadTask.snapshot.metadata.fullPath)
          }
        }
      )
    } catch (error) {
      reject(error)
    }
  })
}
```